# Linear algebra: a finite subset that generates a finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $S\subset V$ a subset that generates $V$.
How can I show that there is a finite subset of $S$ that generates $V$?

Comment: By definition A finite dimensional vector space has a finite basis.

Comment: I know, but how do we know that there is a basis for $V$ in $S$?

Comment: You start with a non-zero vector in S then keep adding linearly independent vectors from S to your list. Since S is spanning and V is finite dimensional you will get your finite generating set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1$ be any vector from $S$. Consider set $B_1=\{v_1\}$. If $\dim V=1$, then $B_1$ is a basis, so generate $V$, is $\dim V>1$, then $B_1$ doesn't genarate $V$, so you can find $v_2 \in S$, but $v_2 \not\in \text{span}B_1$. Let $B_2=\{v_1,v_2\}$. If $\dim V=2$, then $B_2$ is a basis, if $\dim V>3$, , then you can find $v_3 \in S$, but $v_3 \not\in \text{span}B_2$ and $B_3=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$...

By this procedure you finally get basis $B_n$ of $V$ if $\dim V=n$. More formally you can use induction with respect to $\dim V$.